# swiftで音楽を流す時に出るエラーについて。

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let audioPath
            = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bomb", ofType: "m4a")!

        do {
            try player
                = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath))
            player.play()
        } catch {
            // Process error here
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

このように入力し、アプリを実行すると次のようなエラーが出ます。

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

何が原因になっているのでしょうか？

実際、bomb.m4aというファイルはproject内に挿入しておりますし、実際に音楽として聞くこともできます。
しかしアプリの実行ができておりません。
よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: アプリケーションTarget の Build Settings内 Copy Bundle Resources に bomb.m4a は入っていますか？

Answer (score 1):

リソースの取得に失敗していると判断するのが、妥当です。

```
let audioPath
            = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bomb", ofType: "m4a")
print (audioPath != nil ? "Exists" : "Empty")
```

このように、`print()`関数を挿入して、`audioPath`に正しく音声ファイルのファイルパスが代入されているか、確認してください。

---

上の検証の結果、「Empty」になったということなので、パスが通っていないことがわかりました。
もしリソースに`bomb.m4a`がバンドルされていて、それが再生可能でない形式のファイルだったとすると、

> A bundled sound coudn't load.

というメッセージがコンソールに出ますので、その線は考えられません。
なので、ファイル名が一致しない、ビルド時正しくリソースファイルがバンドルされていないという線を疑うべきでしょう。

1. Xcodeの「Product」＞「Clean」をしてからビルドする。
2. シミュレータ、実機から、一度アプリを削除してから、ビルドする。

こういう対処も検討なさってはいかがですか？

Comment: 教えていただいたように入力してみたところ、画像のような状態になりました。
audioPath=emptyとなっているということは、audioPathになにも入っていないという理解でよろしいでしょうか？

また、その場合なぜ代入されていないのでしょうか？

Comment: @Kazuho 回答を追加しました。